# IIS Express Site not loading, however 127.0.0.1 find IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, umbraco

Struggling to get my site to work within IIS Express on Windows 7. (Umbraco) Works fine at work on Server 2012 R2.

IIS Settings
Sitename: umbraco.local
Application Pool: umbraco.local
Physical path (to the root folder)
App pool set at .Net v4.0

hosts file in System32 includes 127.0.0.1  umbraco.local

127.0.0.1 routes to the IIS7 page, as does localhost
umbraco.local can not be found

The root folder permissions is set to Everyone and full access..

any ideas

thanks

Comment: doesn't iis express run on localhost:portnumber?

Comment: http://umbraco.local:80 doesn't work. reverts url back to http://umbraco.local/

Comment: sure because :80 is default in a browser. but are you sure iisexpress is running on :80?

Comment: yup localhost:80 takes me to IIS 'default website'. cheers